# Save / transfer images & videos from local www to camera roll gallery with specific name using cordova ios?

Tags: javascript, ios, image, cordova, camera

I'm using cordova iOS and i want to move/save/transfer files (images and videos) from a local www to the camera roll gallery with a specific name in iOS.
Is it possible and what plugin or JavaScript code could be used?

Comment: First of all learn how to ask questions and post us what you have tried . don't simply ask a question . Quite doe some google search before that . Write a custom plugin and save the image to camera roll. Or try https://github.com/quiply/SaveImage.

Comment: the link you give me has not option to save file with specific name

Comment: there are only 3 parameters

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: Fixed typo and improved some grammar/missing words